# Force using just OPUS codec in Linphone Android

Tags: android, codec, linphone

How can I force to use just Opus Codec in linphone ?
Is there a setting in LinphoneManager.java, or somewhere else (like in LinphoneCore) to change codec setting ?

I found this code in LinphoneManager.java :

```
enableDisableAudioCodec("speex", 32000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("speex", 16000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("speex", 8000, 1, true);
enableDisableAudioCodec("iLBC", 8000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("G722", 8000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("G729", 8000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("AMR", 8000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("AMR-WB", 16000, 1, false);
enableDisableAudioCodec("SILK", 8000, 1, true);
```

can I Just delete that code and just put this :

```
enableDisableAudioCodec("OPUS", 8000, 1, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
private void enableJustOneAudioCodec(String codecName) {
    for (PayloadType pt : LinphoneManager.getLc().getAudioCodecs()) {
        try {
            if (pt.getMime().equals(codecName)) {
                LinphoneManager.getLc().enablePayloadType(pt, true);
            } else {
                LinphoneManager.getLc().enablePayloadType(pt, false);
            }
        } catch (LinphoneCoreException ex) {
            Log.w(ex,"Unable to modify status for codec " + pt.getMime());
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
enableJustOneAudioCodec("OPUS")
```

You can also enable OPUS in linphonerc file:

```
[audio_codec_0]

mime=OPUS
rate=8000
enabled=1
```

but you must explicitly disable the other codecs.

Comment: im using linphonerc to make only PCMA and PCMU true but it not working could you help me?