# Opus Audio Codec in Linphone Android 2013 Version

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, linphone

I want to just enabled Opus Audio Codec in my VOIP application, I have try code from here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635522/force-using-just-opus-codec-in-linphone-android/31652551#31652551](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635522/force-using-just-opus-codec-in-linphone-android/31652551#31652551/%22Link%22)

I try to check findpayloadtype first:

```
for (PayloadType pt : mLc.getAudioCodecs()) {
                pt = mLc.findPayloadType("PCMA", 8000, 1);
                Log.d("LinphoneManager", "PayloadType PCMA : " + pt);
            }

            for (PayloadType pt : mLc.getAudioCodecs()) {
                pt = mLc.findPayloadType("PCMU", 8000, 1);
                Log.d("LinphoneManager","PayloadType PCMU : "+pt);
            }

            for (PayloadType pt : mLc.getAudioCodecs()) {
                pt = mLc.findPayloadType("OPUS", 8000, 1);
                Log.d("LinphoneManager","PayloadType P : "+pt);

            }
```

PCMA and PCMU show value in log :

> [PCMA] clock [8000], bitrate [64000]
>
> [PCMU] clock [8000], bitrate [64000]

but OPUS show null value :

> null

is that something wrong with my code to got OPUS audio codec, or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use "findPayloadType" you don't need any "for" statement.

If findPayloadtype doesn't find any codec maybe it's because the clockrate is wrong (I think opus default clockrate is 48000).

```
findPayloadType(java.lang.String mime, int clockRate, int channels)
```

Why don't you use the overloaded method?

```
 findPayloadType(java.lang.String mime)
```